# Airflow operator to download file from URL and save to disk

Tags: airflow

I want to download a file from a url and save.

The following code doesn't work

```
    download = BashOperator(
        task_id="download",
        bash_command="wget https://github.com/url.csv",
    )
```

It gives

```
INFO - /bin/bash: line 1: wget: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wget is not installed on the airflow worker that runs the bash operator.

You can install wget on the worker or use PythonOperator with existing modules that you don't need to install

```
import urllib.request
from airflow.decorators import task

@task
def download_file(uri, target_path):
    with urllib.request.urlopen(uri) as file:
        with open(target_path, "wt") as new_file:
            new_file.write(file.read())
```